# Intercepting and changing route-based input in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

So I've been using Laravel a lot lately, and it's great! But I've found myself banging my head against the keyboard on this issue I'm having.
I have this pattern:

```
Route::pattern('id', '(\d*|(me))');
```

And this route is required for a lot of my API calls. What it's supposed to do, is give consumers the option to simply append /me at the end of the call, to get info relating to them, so not having to use the userId. I can of course put this login in the controller, no problem, but I would love to be able to put some login in the "pattern", meaning that if this pattern is used, that I can check what userId "/me" correspons to and translate it. I want to do it this way to avoid having to write the same code translating "/me" in all controllers where this is used.

Hope someone has a clever solution out there! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a [Route filter](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters).  Something like this ought to work:

```
Route::filter('route_filter_name', 'F\Q\ClassName');

<?php namespace F\Q;

class ClassName
{
    /**
     * @param Illuminate\Routing\Route
     */
    public function filter($route)
    {
        $userId = $route->getParameter('id');
        if($userId == 'me' && ($user = Auth::user())) {
            $route->setParameter('id', $user->id);
        }
    }
}
```

This is more specific to the route rather than your route pattern as it depends on what name you give the `id` parameter in each route that you want to use it in. An example route that uses it would look like this:

```
Route::get('/users/{id}', [
    'before' => 'route_filter_name', 
    'uses' => 'UserController@showUserInfo' 
]);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for pointing me in the filter direction, I had totally overlooked that.. I did it in a cleaner way than you, but with most of the same building blocks. Thanks a lot!